# Which react declaration to use

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and seen following declaration in few tutorials.

I am confuse on which to use. Is there any guideline on which to prefer under difference situation?

Declaration 1

```
const elem = function() {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>
}
```

Declaration 2

```
const elem2 = <div>Hello World!</div>
```

Declaration 3

```
class App extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering

```
class App extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    );
  }
}
```

is a React component and hence should be used when you wish to create separate Components for different functionalities for you Application which includes states and props being passed.

As per

```
const elem2 = <div>Hello World!</div>
```

it should be used when the JSX elements do not contain extra logic and contian static contents

```
const elem = function() {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>
}
```

should ideally be used when you want to perform certain modification on the data and return the JSX element, also if you wish to perform some conditional returns and stateless retuns

Comment: And accorfing to me I have also said to use constant for static content

Answer (score 0):

You can always use functional components when the component is composed only from the *render* function.

That means, if your component has the following form:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
       ... do something ...
    }
}
```

then you can replace it with

```
const MyComponent = (props, context) => {
    ... do something ...
}
```

Functional components cannot have `state` (they are stateless) and you cannot access the component lifecycle (e.g. `componentDidMount`). You also cannot use pure rendering with them because you cannot override `shouldComponentUpdate`.

They are the purest form of a component, they convert properties into UI and have no other side-effects.

I would recommend to use them as much as possible because they enforce a good programming style (especially with redux architecture) but you won't be able to use them everytime. The "smarter" a component is, the less possible it will be to use a functional component (see [Smart vs Dumb components](https://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/)).

They are especially useful when defining [Higher Order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html).

Also note that you can often combine all approaches, consider

```
render() {
    const renderContents = () => {
        return (
           <div className="contents">
              this.props.children
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
       <div>
          {renderContents}
       </div>
    );
}
```

You can define a "component" inside other component's `render`. As you can see, there is no difference between a function and a functional component. And the same applies for constants. Defining a constant `<div />` is not different from defining a constant string or a number. You don't need to wrap it into a component/function. You can also do things like this:

```
const contents = (() => {
    if (props.children.count === 0) {
       return null;
    }

    return (
       <div>{props.children}</div>
    );
})();
```

This is an immediately invoked function.